# Angular select fire twice when opening

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I don't know why it is happening.

I know my app is quite big and complex but I don't think I'm doing something wrong with my selects.

All my selects fires 2 or even 3 times before show the options.

Basically the code of all my selects is this:

```
<div class="form-group m0">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">My Awesome People:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <select class="input-sm form-control" ng-model="my.people" ng-options="s.id as s.name + ' ' + s.surname for s in people | filter: { available: true }">
            <option value=''>- not set -</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Those selects are populated via Ajax request, on promise, as soon as the data is received I do:

```
angular.copy(data.people, $scope.my.people);
```

Around the controller there is maybe something that conflict the models and generate this behavior.

If the select is not focused it fire 2, 3 times... if it is focused it fire as expected as you can see in the small `gif` I registered.

[image]

I wish to understand what could cause this bug in order to fix it.

Comment: it'll be easier to understand if you could provide the complete code in plunker for example

Comment: its better you leave the fullcode or create a plunker

Comment: Make sure you are not including controller twice or thrice using ng-controller

Comment: It's impossible guys to share everything. For several reasons. I should add several dependencies, I should use a secret API and I should spend a week to let it work. I do not need a solution but just possible causes in order for me to investigate. Thanks.

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/19865

Comment: @tasseKATT Thank you so much, it solved the issue!!!